# Use ES6 syntax instead of `for` loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to check if an array has any `null` value. If it does return `false` otherwise `true`.

How do I turn this

```
checkArray(array){
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === null || array[i] === '')
    return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

into a working example with `map` and fat arrows?

I've tried this

```
checkArray(array){
  array.map(function(item) {
   if (item === null || item === '') {
     return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
  return true;
 })
}
```

But it always returns `true`. Why? Is it because `map` creates a new array?

Comment: Are looking for `Array#filter` ?

Comment: I don't think so, I'll clarify in the question

Comment: `it always returns undefined` because you return nothing from `checkArray`

Comment: @vp_arth sorry I missed a bit. Check my edited code, but even then it always returns `true`

Comment: `array.map` should return `[true, false, false, true]` like array in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the good fit for the underutilised [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
array.some(v => v === '' || v === null);
```

What it does is returns a boolean value that is `true` if the predicate is true for any of the array values, and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method of the Array:

```
var isWithoutEmptyElements = !array.includes(null) && !array.includes('');
```

Comment: your var should be named `hasNotEmpty`, isn't it?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Error in logic? It should be `arr.includes(null) || arr.includes('')`. _I need to check if an array has any null value._

Comment: @Tushar The method should return `false` if there is at least one null or empty string. The logic is correct.

Comment: Why not `isThisArrayDoesNotContainAnyNullOrEmptyStringElements`? =)

Comment: @vp_arth Next time :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `map` variant is that nothing is returned from function.

A better way is to use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
array.find(el => el === null || el === '');
```

```js
var arr = [1, 23, 4, 'something', null, 3235, true];
var found = arr.find(el => el === null || el === '');
console.log(found); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using a [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it creates a new array with the values returned by the callback, but you are not returning any value from `checkArray` that is why you are getting `undefined`.

You want to make sure that none of the item is null or `''` so use [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
checkArray(array) {
  return array.every((item) => item !== undefined && item !== '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `reduce`.

```
var found = array.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    if(acc){
        return true;
    }

    if (value === null || value === ''){
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `some` much better

Comment: Agreed, didnt know ES6 had `some`.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz it actually was there in ES5 as well

Comment: Even more embarrassing :D

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz yep, that's why I called it "underutilised" - because for some magical reason people tend to not knowing about it at all :-) (and it's fine though)